# Sharepoint Calculated Field with Dates

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to write a calculated column that checks the current (today's) month and year and if matches another column it will set a status,  this is how far I have got so far

Thanks in advance for any help

```
=IF([Review Date]>TODAY(), "Review 1", IF([MidPoint Date]>TODAY(),"Mid-Point", ""))
```

This is not working in all scenarios, todays date is 6/11/2023 and if the review date is 2/11/2023 I want the column to show *Review 1*.  However it isn't because I am saying > today. How do I update the formula to check the review date MM/YY and if that equals todays MM/YY it will populate accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to use `TODAY()` in a text calculated column you will have this error:

> Calculated columns cannot contain volatile functions like Today and Me.

The workaround is to use `NOW()` instead.

Next, you have to extract month and year as text: `TEXT(NOW(), "dd/yyyy")`

You can try this formula:

```
=IF(TEXT([Review Date],"mm/yyyy")=TEXT(NOW(),"mm/yyyy"),"Review 1",IF(TEXT([MidPoint Date],"mm/yyyy")=TEXT(NOW(),"mm/yyyy"), "Mid-Point", ""))
```